# orientdb, how insert document field

Tags: nosql, nested, orientdb

I can try to insert into users class ( aka like a table) via shell a structure like this:

```
email: 'test@domain.com'
display_name: 'name surname test'
tags: {id: 1, name: 'first', type:'something'}
```

so some fields when one of them is a document.

I try this query:

```
insert into users (email, display_name, tags) values 
('test@domain.com',
 'name surname test',
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'first', 'type' : 'something'}
)
```

but obtain this error:
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #52: Set of values is missed. Example: ('Bill', 'Stuart', 300)
Command: insert into users (email, display_name, tags) values 
('test@domain.com',
 'name surname test',
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'first', 'type' : 'something'},
)
------------------------------------------------------------^

How can I insert this data into users class?

Answer (score 0):

it's a problem of carriage return. This has been fixed works with 1.0-SNAPSHOT. To avoid to update your OrientDB distribution just remove \n.

Comment: Ok,thanks. In console it work now. I obtain Inserted record 'users#5:7{email:test@domain.com,display_name:name surname test} v0' in 0.001000 sec(s). So, it seems that it doesn't insert a json field element : {'id': 1, 'name': 'first', 'type' : 'something'}. If query users and then display row I obtain: > display 7
--------------------------------------------------
ODocument - Class: users   id: #5:7   v.0
--------------------------------------------------
               email : test@domain.com     
        display_name : name surname test

Comment: Just executed and works perfectly. The retrieved document is: {
  "@type": "d", "@rid": "#61:0", "@version": 0, "@class": "users", 
    "email": "test@domain.com", 
      "display_name": "name surname test", 
        "tags": {"id": 1, "name": "first", "type": "something"}
}